# How to stream a large CSV response from a compojure API so that the whole response is not held in memory at once?

Tags: csv, clojure, out-of-memory, large-files, compojure

I'm new to using compojure, but have been enjoying using it so far. I'm
currently encountering a problem in one of my API endpoints that is generating
a large CSV file from the database and then passing this as the response body.

The problem I seem to be encountering is that the whole CSV file is being kept
in memory which is then causing an out of memory error in the API. What is the
best way to handle and generate this, ideally as a gzipped file? Is it possible
to stream the response so that a few thousand rows are returned at a time? When
I return a JSON response body for the same data, there is no problem returning
this.

Here is the current code I'm using to return this:

```
(defn complete
  "Returns metrics for each completed benchmark instance"
  [db-client response-format]
  (let [benchmarks  (completed-benchmark-metrics {} db-client)]
    (case response-format
      :json  (json-grouped-output field-mappings benchmarks)
      :csv   (csv-output benchmarks))))

(defn csv-output [data-seq]
  (let [header (map name (keys (first data-seq)))
        out    (java.io.StringWriter.)
        write  #(csv/write-csv out (list %))]
    (write header)
    (dorun (map (comp write vals) data-seq))
    (.toString out)))
```

The `data-seq` is the results returned from the database, which I think is a
lazy sequence. I'm using yesql to perform the database call.

Here is my compojure resource for this API endpoint:

```
(defresource results-complete [db]
  :available-media-types  ["application/json" "text/csv"]
  :allowed-methods        [:get]
  :handle-ok              (fn [request]
                            (let [response-format (keyword (get-in request [:request :params :format] :json))
                                  disposition     (str "attachment; filename=\"nucleotides_benchmark_metrics." (name response-format) "\"")
                                  response        {:headers {"Content-Type" (content-types response-format)
                                                             "Content-Disposition" disposition}
                                                   :body    (results/complete db response-format)}]
                              (ring-response response))))
```

Comment: Why do you have the `dorun` there? It's whole purpose is to be non-lazy. I'm pretty sure `.toString` is non-lazy, and I'm not sure about `keys` & `vals`.

Comment: @AlanThompson, it's my understanding that `dorun` does not keep the head of the sequence and so can be used for side effects such as writing to a string buffer.

Comment: Yes, but it does cause the sequence to be evaluated immediately, not lazily.

Comment: This page talks about laziness when working with csv files. Just in case it helps: https://github.com/clojure/data.csv

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I was able to create a solution based on the linked articles and documentation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to all the suggestion that were provided in this thread, I was able to create a solution using `piped-input-stream`:

```
(defn csv-output [data-seq]
  (let [headers     (map name (keys (first data-seq)))
        rows        (map vals data-seq)
        stream-csv  (fn [out] (csv/write-csv out (cons headers rows))
                              (.flush out))]
    (piped-input-stream #(stream-csv (io/make-writer % {})))))
```

This differs from my solution because it does not realise the sequence using `dorun` and does not create a large `String` object either. This instead writes to a `PipedInputStream` connection asynchronously [as described by the documentation](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.util.io.html):

> Create an input stream from a function that takes an output stream as its
>   argument. The function will be executed in a separate thread. The stream
>   will be automatically closed after the function finishes.

Answer (score 3):

Your csv-output function completely realises the dataset and turns it into a string. To lazily stream the data, you'll need to return something other than a concrete data type like a String. [This](https://nelsonmorris.net/2015/04/22/streaming-responses-using-ring.html) suggests ring supports returning a stream, that can be lazily realised by Jetty. [The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581644/how-to-serve-the-stream-pdf-with-ring) might prove useful.

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with the streaming of large csv file. My solution was to use [httpkit-channel](http://www.http-kit.org/channel.html#get-channel) to stream every single line of the **data-seq** to the client and then close the channel. My solution looks like that:

```
[org.httpkit.server :refer :all]

(fn handler [req]
    (with-channel req channel (let [header "your$header"
                                    data-seq ["your$seq-data"]]
                                    (doseq [line (cons header data-seq)]
                                       (send! channel
                                              {:status  200
                                              :headers {"Content-Type" "text/csv"}
                                              :body    (str line "\n")}
                                              false))
                                    (close channel))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm not familiar with httpkit server, I ended up answering this question using `piped-input-stream` because that fits with my existing clojure API stack which includes liberator and compojure. I'll likely channels in future for larger data.